# QGIS - set an Action checked by objectName (SnappingTool - EnableTracingAction)

Tags: pyqgis

I would like to enable the Tracing Tool at QGIS startup.

With the following code, this works great.

```
for x in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QToolBar):
if x.objectName() =='mSnappingToolBar':
    for icon in x.actions():
        if icon.objectName() == 'EnableTracingAction':
            icon.setChecked(True)
```

Since I know the `objectName` of the toolbar and the action, I'm wondering if there is a more direct solution.
Something like this: (this obviously doesn't work)

```
iface.QToolBar('mSnappingTool').QAction('EnableTracingAction').setChecked(True)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A more direct solution:

```
iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QAction, 'EnableTracingAction')[0].setChecked(True)
```